# vertx httpserver wait for port listening

Tags: java, vert.x, reactivex, vertx3

I´m having an issue with a RC running my server. My integration test are hitting the server before this one startup. 
How can I ensure that the port of the server is actually listening before I start my test?.

I was using httpServer.listen(port, handle) feature but seems does not works as the API specify.

```
      RxUtils.<HttpServer>observe(handler -> httpServer.requestHandler(addUrlHandlers())
                                                            .listen(port, handler)).doOnCompleted(
            () -> lifecycleEvent("Successfully Registered handlers {}:{}", getName(), port))
                                                                                   .doOnError(t -> lifecycleError(
                                                                                           "Error while registering handlers for port {} in {}", port,
                                                                                           getName(), t))
                                                                                   .map(o -> Boolean.TRUE);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

this is my test code, `context.asyncAssertSuccess()` make sure the vertx is started

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class LunarCalendarVerticleIntegrationTest {
    private Vertx vertx;

    @Before
    public void setUp(TestContext context) {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getName(),context.asyncAssertSuccess());
    }
}
```

Comment: It just waits until deployment Verticle, and if in Verticle there is startHttpServer you will not wait